# How to add date to navigation bar

Tags: php, css

I've created a new navigation bar on this site:  http://www.tomorrowstrends.com/

I'd like to add the date on the right hand side (on the grey menu below the blue one).

I thought I could add this to my new navigation php file (thirdnav.php):

```
<?php echo '<div class="date"<div>'; date(get_option('date_format')); ?>
```

So I would have this:

```
<?php 
if ( has_nav_menu( 'thirdnav' ) ) {
echo '<div id="subnav"><div>';  
wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container_id' => 'thirdnav' , 'menu_class' => 'menu thirdnav superfish sf-js-enabled', 'theme_location' => 'thirdnav') ); 
echo '</div></div>'; 
} ?>

<?php echo '<div class="date"<div>'; date(get_option('date_format')); ?>
```

But I need to style it and I don't know the proper syntax for creating a class for the date within the echo statement.

How is that done?  Am I doing this correctly?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please add an image illustrating your desired output. A question should not rely on an external site.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to hook into the `wp_nav_menu_{$menu_name}_items` filter and add your date item in there:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_106781_add_menu_items_hook' );

function wpse_106781_add_menu_items_hook() {
    $theme_location  = 'thirdnav';
    $theme_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

    /* Make sure the theme location is valid */
    if ( ! isset( $theme_locations[ $theme_location ] ) )
        return;

    /* Get the navigation menu assigned to that theme location */
    $menu = get_term( $theme_locations[ $theme_location ], 'nav_menu' );

    /* Make sure the menu is valid */
    if ( ! isset( $menu->slug ) )
        return;

    /* Add the filter hook */
    add_filter( "wp_nav_menu_{$menu->slug}_items", 'wpse_106781_thirdnav_menu_items' );
}

function wpse_106781_thirdnav_menu_items( $items ) {
    $items .= sprintf(
        '<li class="navmenu-date"><time datetime="%s">%s</time></li>',
        date( 'Y-m-d' ),
        date( get_option( 'date_format' ) )
    );
    return $items;
};
```

As this function affects the front-end appearance, it would be appropriate to place it in the theme's `functions.php` file.

Not only will it add the current date to the `thirdnav` menu, it will also use the appropriate [HTML5 `<time>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time) to represent the date. You can use the `wp_nav_menu()` function in your templates as normal.

You can style this item by using the class that is between `<li class="` and `"><time` - in this case it is `thirdnav-date`, but it can be any [valid HTML class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#class) you choose.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  When I try to place this in functions.php I get a parse error.  Is there some syntax I have to add or specific location in the code to put it?

Comment: @user35399 You might be using an old version of PHP - I've updated the code so it should work now. It needs to go in `functions.php` after the `<?php` and before the `?>` (if there is one). If you'd rather not mess around with the functions.php file, you can just copy-and-paste it into the [code snippets](http://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets) plugin.

Comment: I've edited your code -- I think the parse error mentioned by @user35399 could be due to the original `spritf()` and/or a missing comma before the first call to `date()`.

Comment: I put in the code but the date is not showing up.  Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: @user35399 I just tested this, and you're right. It turns out that you can't add items to a menu by it's theme location, you need to use the menu-specific slug. I've added a function to retrieve the menu slug from the theme location. The updated code will work now.

Comment: I added this to functions.php and got a syntax error.  Tried adding with the code snippets plugin and nothing happened.  Sorry to be a pain.  I really need to learn php!

Comment: Can you let me know what the syntax error was?

Comment: Just tried again and it worked.  I'm sorry, it must have been an error on my part as to where I placed the code. I really appreciate your help. Now I just need to know how to target the date for styling.  #navmenu-date ?

Comment: The target is a class so it would be `.navmenu-date`

Comment: I put this in the stylesheet but it had no effect:  .navmenu-date {
 float: right;
}  is there something else I must add?

Comment: This is because a rule elsewhere in the stylesheet id overriding it. Try making the selector more specific eg: `#subnav .navmenu-date`

Comment: No problem. Remember to mark this answer as correct using the green tick symbol.